# Not getting any result in Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

```
Cursor allDetail = allDatabase2.rawQuery("Select "+ TaskDatabaseManager.KEY_ROWID + ","+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMES + ","+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DESCRIPTION + " from "+ TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE + " where "+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DATE + "= '"   + LaunchActivity.selectedDate + "'", null);
```

I am not able to correctly compare the two date's in the database. Any help regarding how to compare them.My Android Database Schema is

```
  static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("+KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
        + TASK_DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(200)  NULL,"+TASK_DATE+ " DATE  Null, "+ TASK_TIMES
        + "  VARCHAR(30)  NULL," + TASK_STATUS + " BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE);";
```

Comment: What does `LaunchActivity.selectedDate` return?

Comment: It returns a string that is a date in yyyy/MM/dd format Any solution @iaindownie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on a Google Forum:

SQLite treats dates as strings. If you don't store your date/times
using ISO-8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), you can't compare them,
since only in ISO-8601 format do lexical comparisons work as expected.

Comment: Thank you.. Actually the mistake was that date which I inserted in the database was for example 2013/8/2 and I was comparing this with 2013/08/02 ( which was the LaunchActivity.selecteddate value)

Comment: OK, if my answer helped, that's the main thing. Accept it perhaps?

Comment: Sorry but it didn't..  But how to accept an answer I will accept your . I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You should test if your `Cursor` contains any data to determine if is empty or not. In your case your table probably doesn't contain rows.

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   // is not empty
}
else {
  // is null (problem with SQLiteDatabase) or empty
}
```

So now you know where is problem. If Cursor is empty problem can be with **database** (contains no rows) or with **LaunchActivity.selectedDate** variable you are adding to where clause.

### Notes:

- Please remove from your `CREATE_QUERY` semicolon **`;`** This symbol
  creates only problems
- Don't use "hardcoded" statements but use parametrized statements with
  an usage of placeholders. There statements are much more safe and human readable.

### Example:

```
String query = "select * from table where _id = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      // fetch data from Cursor
   } while (c.moveToNext());
}
else {
   // Cursor is null or empty
}
```

Comment: Actually when I removed the where clause in the query.  I m getting results from the database. And thank you for the tips

Comment: @AnuranjitMaindola so in this case, problem is how a mentioned with where clause -> any record has this value in column or value is not initialised how you expected. Try to print this value and let me know.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: @AnuranjitMaindola problem is LaunchActivity.selectedDate, its value have no row as date column or selectedDate is not initialised properly.

Comment: I logged the value of selecteddate and it is returning the date in the same format as it is inserted in the database

Comment: @AnuranjitMaindola so problem is in comparing. You cannot compare dates on database level as String. Try to convert them to long or another approach is to fetch all rows and one by one test date column and if it same as selectedDate, you will return this row.